# Unable to create database instance in IBM Cloud

Tags: db2

[there is some internal server error while creating database instance in cloud][1]

[1]:[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5tty.png]

Answer (score 1):

Raise a support ticket with IBM.

Operational issues on commercial cloud services are not for stackoverflow.

Additionally, if you are on the "lite" plan (as suggested by your image), there is no ability to create a Database instance. Instead, you can only connect to a shared multi-tenanted database with your your account. It has a schema which is your account-name.